# Change default system file copier in Linux

Tags: python, linux, copy-paste

I have coded a python app to manage file copies on linux, I want to know how can I get it to process copy/paste calls, like those launched by pressing ctrl + c/ ctrl + v  or right click / Copy..., or drag and drop, instead of using system copier.

Can I do this for all deb based linux dist. or its on different ways for Ubuntu, Mint, Debian, and so on????

Forgive my English and thanks in advance!

Comment: Rewrite the file manager.

Comment: Just wondering - is there anything else I could help with ... if not, maybe consider accepting that answer ... although you might not like what I have told you; but I dont think that you will here much else here.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, you can't.

Long answer: the component that does "copy&paste" is not alone defined by the distribution. This is a function of the desktop system / window manager. In other words: there is no such thing as the "default system file" copier for "Linux".

There are file mangers like dolphin for KDE; or nautilus on gnome that all come with their **own** implementation of file copy. Some good, some not so much (try copying a whole directory with thousands of files with nautilus).

But the real question here: why do you want to do that? What makes you think that your file-copy implementation that requires an **interpreter** to run ... is suited to replace the defaults that come with Linux? Why do you think that your re-invention of an existing wheel will be better at doing anything?!

Edit: if your reason to "manage" system copy is some attempt to prevent the user from doing certain things ... you should better look into file permissions and such ideas. Within a Linux environment, you simply **can't manage** what the user is doing in the first place by manipulating some tools. Instead: understand the management capabilities that the OS offers to you, and use those!

Comment: Well I  have been absent for some days so I was not till now I have check these answer, thanks everyone..and some comments

Comment: First GhostCat... the fact python language is interpreted doesnt make it much slower than C implementation of cp, just a fews ms because as you may know Python or Cpython its just C under a wrapper so to speak, I have been checking some benchmaks and you can see if you want this  http://kracekumar.com/post/53685731325/cp-command-implementation-and-benchmark-in-python (a little old but cp is almost the same since 1993/4) . Second...I dont think I will reinvent the wheel as you said because neither of the copier I have test so far available on GNU/Linux provide (alltogether) ....

Comment: queue handle: like removing or chaging the order of copy request while copying, clear statistics of copy, pause option, failded items queue and treatment, copy queue recovery and not to continue the functionalities that apps like Supercopier, Ultracopier, etc provide for W,

Comment: and thats all, some people could say you can make a bash script with a bunch of utils to do all these stuff and they would be right but some others would appreciate this app, just check on google the web for....supercopier for linux????, good copy handle for Linux??? or questions like that and you see there planty much questions and needs than actual and real andpractical solutions,,thanks anyway...I appreciate you time and knowledge!

Comment: In there end, there are **two** dimensions in here: A) why would a user want to use a different "system copy" command B) how to put that in place technically. Probably you have good arguments for A) ... but that doesn't change the fact that the "B)" part might not be working out. As you can see, nobody else stood up here and gave you a simple list of steps to get there. Because it might be either very hard; or even impossible to do what you are asking for.

Comment: ok I understand you but I see here a challenge and more reasons to find a solutions...thanks!!!